# A black box showing while voting

Tags: bug, downvotes, upvotes, tooltips

I am getting a black box (I think it might be a tool tip) while quickly doing upvote/downvote.

### Screenshot:

[image]

I guess the tool tip container box opened first (black box) and the rendered text later. I get this in Google Chrome: **Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

### Update:

Now I can see this same problem some other places also while quickly hovering on recent inbox message, achievements, review queues, etc. So it should be my graphics driver problem. Because I am unable to reproduce this issue in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Can't repo, but yeah looks like the tooltip which is controller by the browser, don't think there's anything anyone (here) can do about it.

Comment: @George Are you sure? it can't repo?

Comment: No repro either. Does this happen on what browser? Have you tried with a different browser? An all questions? One question? Restarted your browser? Etc, etc?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'm sure **I** can't reproduce it.

Comment: I got this from google chrome `Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Are other tooltips on other parts of the site, and other sites, working for you?  Has this happened once, or does it happen every time you try to load the tooltip?

Comment: But am not able to see this `IE11`

Comment: Looks like something's up with your graphics card or its driver. Do other sites work properly? It's simply an `<a title="..." />` so should be trivial to reproduce.

Comment: @CodeCaster But it is working in IE browser

Comment: Yes, that's a different browser, using a different rendering engine. You still didn't answer my question: is this problem isolated to Stack Overflow, or do other sites display the same behavior? Because if the latter, this question has nothing to do here on Meta.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your browser plugins / extensions?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have use the lot tool tip in my application. But am not getting any problem.

Comment: @RameshRajendran Just to clarify, you don't mean quickly upvoting followed by downvoting, repeatedly? You just mean quickly upvoting **or** downvoting something right?

Comment: @George Yes, Am quickly doing up-voting and down-voting. Okay i will check this from my laptop

Comment: @RameshRajendran So you upvote something, downvote the same thing, upvote the same thing, etc and that's the only time you're able to reproduce this bug?

Answer (score 10):

There is no code involved in showing the tooltip, this is the complete markup:

```
<a class="vote-up-off" 
   title="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear">
   up vote
</a>
```

The only interesting CSS for the `vote-up-off`and `vote-up-on` classes that might cause an extra load in the form of a network action is the background-image but that is a sprite PNG and shared with many elements/CSS classes so if you would notice it, you would only do so once.

The combination of your browser, any pending actions in the browser or current tab, operating system, Anti-Virus, video drivers, graphics card, Network utilization, CPU, RAM, current overall load etc, is causing that effect.  Are you on a Virtual/Terminal/Citrix server by any chance?
There is nothing SE can do to fix issues with your local setup.

Comment: Shall we take the css class of `vote-up-off`??

Comment: @RameshRajendran: what would that achieve? That has nothing to do with tooltip rendering in your browser.